# showing the result of the long term task in Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a class in Java. the class contains some functions. each function print its result in output. 
based on the how initiate the function the output write in console or web page. my class like something like the following class

```
    public class DBBuilder
    {
      private static DBBuilder _obj;

      private PrintWriter out; 
      public static DBBuilder Initiate(PrintWriter output)
      {
         obj = new DBBuilder();
         obj._out = output
      }
      public static DBBuilder Initiate()
      {
      }

      private void Print(String Message)
      {
        if(_out == null)
               System.out.println(Message);
        else
               _out.println(Message);
      }
      public void DoSomething()
      {
          //some code
          this.Print("Create Node [ "+ n.getNodeID() +" ].");
      }
  }
```

so the main code use this class for converting a type of database to other type of database. in addition, DBBuilder may print 5000 line in output. everything is Ok in console but in Web Application I use Ajax by Jquery , the result doesn't show until the converting mechanism reaches to the end of flow. When it reaches to the end whole of output appear in web page.

**Is there any way that web application act like console application. I mean when the Print method invoke the result will shown in the web page by Ajax.**

Answer (score 0):

If you're rendering contents to an object by calling the jquery method, there's no way to have response line by line like console unless refreshing output object for every single line. The only way would be to simply send the parameter and receive respose line by line using ajax in a loop.